# Joomla: Display part of menu

Tags: joomla, menu, joomla-module

I'm trying to make a small left menu in my Joomla articles. Since I use the SP Pagebuilder to display the articles, the module on my page isn't also displayed on my article. With the advanced module manager I was able to put a module in my articles, but there's one problem: I can't display my menu.

Say you have this kind of menu:
*Home
*Item
 *Item 1
  *Item 1.1
  *Item 1.2
  *Item 1.3
 *Item 2
  *Item 2.1
  *Item 2.2

On the articles I've put in Item 1.1, 1.2 and 1.3, I want to display a menu with these parts:
*1.1
*1.2
*1.3
On 2.1 and 2.2 it's: 
*2.1
*2.2

Still, my articles are technically in the "home" part of my menu. The url should be something like: www.mysite.be/component/content/article/item/item1-1/article1

If you then place a menu module with these options:
Menu: Menu1
Basic Item: Item1
Start: 3
Stop: 3
It doesn't wanna display it, since my articles aren't in the "basic item" (being item1), but in the "home".

Is there any way make a menu that uses this? I want it because if I add an item (say "item 1.4"), then I don't have to add another link.
Please help...

Thank you in advance. I hope you understand what I mean XD

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i got your question right, but normally, if you set up an new menu-module you can set the Menu you want to use and the Base-Item (Home) where all the Sub Items are placed.

So if you want to only display the Sub-Items of home you normally should then set start-level to "1" (Since your base item is already "Home" and you want to display down all items from home... so if you choose "3" it would start displaying menus that are the third sublevel of "home") and end-level to "all" (or the maximal depth you choose), assign the right position for the Module and give it a go.